# Koa2: middle layer to combine multiple REST API calls

Tags: koa2

I'm investigating how to use node.js as a middle layer to combine multiple REST API calls into single request. (in this way, save the roundtrips between browser and server)
Firstly, I used `express` framework and `request-promise` library, find a solution as following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request-promise');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8003;
app.get('/merge', function(req, res) {
    var data1, data2, data3;
    request('http://localhost:8000/api1').then(function(body) {
        data1 = JSON.parse(body);
        return request('http://localhost:8000/api2');
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        data2 = JSON.parse(body);
        return request('http://localhost:8000/api3');
    })
    .then(function(body) {
        data3 = JSON.parse(body);
        var alldata = Object.assign({}, data1, data2, data3);
        res.json(alldata);
    })
});
```

this solution is `promise` based, the `request-promise` return a promise, which allows me to chain 3 API calls and merge `data1`, `data2` and `data3` together as above.

In `Koa2(async/await)` how to do this?

Edit, find the solution as following:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var serve = require('koa-static');
var route = require('koa-route');
const request = require('request-promise');
var app = new koa();


const main = async ctx => {

    let name = await getName();
    let city = await getCity();
    let gender = await getGender();
    ctx.response.body = `${name}${city}${gender}`;
};

function getName() {
   return request('http://localhost:8000/api1');
};

function getCity() {
  return request('http://localhost:8000/api2');
};

function getGender() {
   return request('http://localhost:8000/api3');
};

app.use(route.get('/merge', main));
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it on your own? If so what was the exact problem you have encountered?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `async-await` you will have to wait for each promise to resolve sequentially which may not be efficient if you don't need to feed the results from one request to the next. Instead you could execute the promises in parallel using `Promise.all` which will return an array of the results.

```
function getName() {
  return request('http://localhost:8000/api1');
};

function getCity() {
  return request('http://localhost:8000/api2');
};

function getGender() {
  return request('http://localhost:8000/api3');
};

const main = async ctx => {
  const results = await Promise.all([getName(), getCity(), getGender()]);
  // return the results as a single string
  ctx.response.body = results.join('');
};
```

`Promise.all` rejects if any of the promise elements are rejected. If one of the promises rejects immediately, then `Promise.all` will reject immediately. This fail-fast behaviour is an additional performance benefit.